# Is there a way to filter a fixed percentage sample from a specific categoric variable?

Tags: r, random, dplyr, statistics

Say I have a population of 1000 patients with data of their sex. I'm being asked to draw a sample of size n that meets strictly that 65% of them must be male.

Some sample data (in here, the sex distribution is 50%-50%):

```r
data <- data.frame(patient_id = 1:1000,
               sex = append(rep("male", 500),
                            rep("female", 500))
                   )
```

Can't really see a way to solve this task using `sample_n` or `sample_frac` in `dplyr`.

Result data should be something like this for n = 500, but with random patient_ids.

```r
data.frame(patient_id = 1:500,
           sex = append(rep("male", 325),
                        rep("female", 175))
           )
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: You can have E() of drawing 65% males but there isn't a way to guarantee it

Comment: `tibble(
  n = 500,
  sex = c(
    rep("male", (n * .65)),
    rep("female", n * 0.35)
  ),
  patient_id = seq_len(n)
)`

Comment: I mean, the result data provided was just an example of what it should look like, the answer must come from the data itself. @Bruno Can you explain a little further? I'm also thinking this is statistically unfeasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `bind_rows` and filter them separately. First, let's set the values for the number of rows so that it can give flexibility if you want to change the percentage:

```
library(tidyverse)

number_of_sample <- 500

male_pct <- 0.65

number_of_male <- number_of_sample * male_pct

number_of_female <- number_of_sample - number_of_male

#For reproducibility setting the seed
set.seed(4)

data %>%
  filter(sex=='male') %>%
  sample_n(size = number_of_male) %>%
  bind_rows(data %>%
              filter(sex=='female') %>%
              sample_n(size = number_of_female))-> sampled_data
```

Checking the numbers:

```
sampled_data %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise(count=n())

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  sex    count
  <chr>  <int>
1 female   175
2 male     325
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I think your solution was the most clear one.

Answer (score 1):

Another tidyverse option.

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 150

view <- slice_sample(filter(data, sex == 'male'), n = round(n*0.65)) %>%
  bind_rows(slice_sample(filter(data, sex == 'female'), n = round(n*0.35)))
```

Counting the rows gives us:

```
count(view, sex)

#      sex  n
# 1 female 52
# 2   male 98
```

Comment: This code will not draw a random sample. It takes only the first 65% of men and first 35% of women, not a random sample. Could be updated to use `sample_frac()` though instead of square brackets with the actual proportion that is needed calculated beforehand.

Comment: @c_j_fairfield: Thank you very much for spotting my error. I have updated the post using your great suggestion.

Comment: Forgot about `slice_sample()` - great function. This would indeed give random sample and works for original question assuming proportion of male and female start at 50%. Similar to my answer would need a tweak to scale the proportions if the original proportion M:F was not 50:50. This is covered though in @Shibaprasadb's answer

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution using nesting of data in one pipeline. The proportions would need changed if you aren't using a 50/50 split.

```
library(tidyverse)
sampled_data = data %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(prop = c(0.65, 0.35)) %>% 
  mutate(samples = map2(data, prop, sample_frac)) %>% 
  select(-data, - prop) %>% 
  unnest(samples)

sampled_data %>% count(sex)

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  sex        n
  <fct>  <int>
1 female   175
2 male     325
```

Comment: Is that mean that some male are duplicates?

Comment: No males are duplicates. Just the same data as in the question